# OUTLIER HANDLING ON TARGET VARIABLE, IS THAT POSSIBLE?

Tags: error-handling, data-cleaning, outliers, feature-engineering

I'm new to machine learning, I want to ask about outlier handling in target variable. at first, I found that there were so many outliers in my target variable and that my model (linear regression) have high RMSE value too. I tried to change target outliers to median and made my RMSE turn to 0.0. it's kinda weird, i want to ask is that possible to handle target variable outliers or there is any other option?

Here's the code i wrote down:

```
#boston dataset

###
boston['MEDV'] = np.select([(boston['MEDV'] < bot) | (boston['MEDV'] > top)],[boston['MEDV'].median()])

X = boston[list(boston.columns[0:-1])]
y = boston['MEDV']

X_train, X_test,y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=1)

###
reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(X_train,y_train)

y_pred = reg.predict(X_train)
residual = y_train - y_pred
mse = np.mean(residual**2)
rmse = np.sqrt(mse)

MAPE = mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_train, y_pred)
print('RMSE :',rmse, '\n', 'MAPE :', MAPE)

#the results show that RMSE and MAPE : 0.0
```